# Fullpage.js infinit scrolling horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using [FullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) to have sliding effects.

I did the following:
There is a section containing 2 slides from which I am getting the following behavior.

slide 1   **->** press on next button  **->**  slide 2  **->** press on next button **->** slide 2 then slide 1

I do not want it to pass by slide 2 before going back to slide 1 , I want it to keep moving right like a flow not right and then at the last slide it goes left all the way back to slide number 1.

Comment: Can you share your code please ?

Comment: Added plugin link and formatted question

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Continuous Horizontal Extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/continuous-horizontal.html) for fullpage.js.

Then use the option `continuousHorizontal:true`.